# What is difference between God and Jesus Christ in Mark 10:17-19?

Tags: life-of-jesus

I have a question about some verses in Bible Mark 10:17-19

> As Jesus started on his way, a man ran up to him and fell on his knees before him. “Good teacher,” he asked, “what must I do to inherit eternal life?”
>
> “Why do you call me good?” Jesus answered. “No one is good—except God alone. You know the commandments: ‘You shall not murder, you shall not commit adultery, you shall not steal, you shall not give false testimony, you shall not defraud, honor your father and mother.

In these verses a man came to Jesus Christ (peace be upon him) and asked some thing by saying him a GOOD TEACHER. In reply Jesus Christ (peace be upon him) said that No one is good except God alone. Mean Jesus Christ (peace be upon him) is making difference between himself and God here. Can you please tell me that Who is God here and after God what is the status of Jesus Christ (peace be upon him) here because he called God someone other here.

Answer (score 2):

No one is good except God;Jesus wanted this man to realise that if truely believes that Jesus is good then He is God,therefore Jesus proved to this man that Himself was God.

Comment: @ZainFarooq It seems you haven't understood this answer: while brief, it actaully reflects orthodox Christian beliefs and provides an answer to a dilemma that Christians have being thinking about and discussing for the last 2 millenia. Whether you understand it or not, your response could certainly afford to be more civil.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer here. Since this question is very similar to another one that has already been asked here, it will likely be closed. Your answer, though it certainly reflects Christian belief, is shorter than what's preferred here. See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) Meanwhile, I hope you'll stick around and read some of the other questions and answers here.

Comment: This is the correct answer, from a Christian perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Does this mean Jesus Christ  is making difference between himself and God here?

No, but the opposite is the case. He did not say, "I am not good because only God is good," but he *asked*, "why do *you call me good*? Only God is good." He is asking, in effect, "Only God is good, yet you call me good- do you believe I am God?"

He says "I am the good Shepard." (John 10:11)

Comment: He says in one part `Why do you call me good?` He says that why do you call ME.. than in other part `No one is good—except God alone`.  No one is good except GOD. There are clearly two persons here. One is ME and other is GOD

Comment: The problem here is not about GOOD... There can be different levels of GOOD that Jesus Christ referred this to GOD. Like here, person called Jesus Christ a `Good Teacher` but Jesus Christ refused to accept this one and referred it to God. But problem here is that He used to words `Me` and `God`.

Comment: @ZainFarooq I am very happy to discuss this with you in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room).

Comment: Andrew, fyi, a user needs to have at least 20 rep before they can participate in site chatrooms.

Comment: @ZainFarooq I am very happy to discuss this with you in chat _sometime in the future_.

Comment: Hi, Can't you discuss here

Comment: @ZainFarooq No, comments should be for quick notes concerning the question or answer, like "can you clarify what you mean by ____"or "I suggest that you edit the phrase _____ to say _____" or to post links to related questions. After a while, all discussion-type comments (like this one) are deleted by moderators, and they generally dislike when we give them superfluous tasks. Once you have 20 rep points, you can join chat. I will up-vote this question to help you on your way.